# "Unresolved attribute reference" in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I get an `unresolved attribute reference 'get_opposite_node' for class 'list'` warning in PyCharm, even though the code works fine.

This the relevant part of the code:

```
    def bfs(self, start, end):
        visited = {start}  # visited set contains int indices
        start_node = self.Node(start)
        q = deque()
        q.append(start_node)  # deque contains Node objects
        while q:
            cur_node = q.popleft()  # Node object
            if cur_node.idx == end:
                return cur_node 

            for edge in self.get_out_edges(cur_node):
                # HERE IS WHERE I GET THE WARNING:
                child = self.Node(edge.get_opposite_node(i))
                child_idx = child.idx
                if child_idx not in visited:
                    visited.add(child_idx)
                    q.append(child)
                    child.parent = cur_node
        return None

    def get_out_edges(self, node):
        return self.adj[node.idx]

    def add_edge(self, line):
        # line is just a string from the input file 
        (v, u, w) = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
        e = Edge(v,u,w)
        self.adj[v].append(e)
        self.adj[u].append(e)
        self.edges.append(e)
```

`self.adj` is the list of lists:`self.adj = [[] for _ in range(N)]`, which is later filled by the edges of class `Edge`:

```
class Edge:
    def __init__(self, v, u, w):
        self.v = v
        self.u = u
        self.w = w

    def get_node(self):
        return self.v

    def get_opposite_node(self, k=None):
        return self.u if k == self.v or k is None else self.v
```

So, basically, while `self.adj[i]` contains `Edge`s, PyCharm thinks that it contains lists(?). Is there a way to 'convince' PyCharm that it is not like this?

Answer (score 3):

PyCharm is confused because you have explicitly declared `adj` to be a `list` of (empty) `list`s. It can't tell that you've subsequently overwritten each element of `adj` with an object which understands `get_opposite_node()`. But it does know that you can't `get_opposite_node()` on a `list`.

You could work around this by declaring `adj` to contain a `list` of `None` instead of a `list` of empty `list`s. The below may clarify a little:

```
class RealEdge:
    def get_something(self):
        return "something"


class SomeEdgyThing:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.adj = [[] for _ in range(size)]


class SomeOtherEdgyThing:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.adj = [None for _ in range(size)]


class ReallyEdgyThing:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.adj = [RealEdge() for _ in range(size)]


my_complicated_thing = SomeEdgyThing(7)
for i in range(len(my_complicated_thing.adj)):
    my_complicated_thing.adj[i] = RealEdge()
# PyCharm warning:
#     Unresolved attribute reference 'get_something' for class 'list'
# Runs fine, because we overwrote all the values in adj
# with RealEdges instead of lists.
print(my_complicated_thing.adj[1].get_something())

my_thing = SomeEdgyThing(7)
try:
    # PyCharm warning:
    #     Unresolved attribute reference 'get_something' for class 'list'
    # Also a runtime error:
    #     AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_something'
    print(my_thing.adj[1].get_something())
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)

my_other_thing = SomeOtherEdgyThing(7)
try:
    # PyCharm doesn't complain.
    # Does it assume NoneType is part of a union type...?
    # Runtime error:
    #     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_something'
    print(my_other_thing.adj[1].get_something())
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)

real_thing = ReallyEdgyThing(7)
# No error
print(real_thing.adj[1].get_something())
```

Output:

```
something
'list' object has no attribute 'get_something'
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_something'
something
```

I suspect that you don't really need to write `self.adj = [[] for _ in range(N)]` and that `self.adj = [None for _ in range(N)]` will serve just as well and will cause the warning to disappear.

Now, you are still exposed to the case where your code runs in the wrong order somehow and you try to call `get_opposite_node()` on a member of `adj` that you haven't updated to contain a real `Edge`. You just aren't being warned about it any more. For that reason I would recommend wrapping these calls inside a `try: ... except AttributeError:` block.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. `self.adj` is not a list of `Edge`s but rather a list of LISTS of `Edge`s. `self.adj` is basically a list where each index corresponds to the index of the Node in the graph. And every list inside `self.adj` contains a list of Edges going out of this Node. So, for a given Node, function `get_out_edges` returns a list of Edges (which I then iterate through: `for edge in self.get_out_edges(cur_node)`). I have updates the original question with one more function, which maybe will give more info about the problem.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit different. Here, PyCharm is confused because it doesn't know that `node.idx` is not a `slice()` (which would mean `get_out_edges` would return a list of lists). You can solve this with type annotations if you are using a sufficiently recent version of python 3 by changing the method signature of `get_out_edges` to `def get_out_edges(self, node) -> list:` or adding an annotation to `Node.idx` wherever that is declared to explicitly state it is an `int`. Having the full code would help.